# Esperar pagina caregar para o selenium em python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Criei um programa para logar no site, mas ele carrega muito lentamente quando abre, e para isso preciso colocar sleep(40), que espera 40 segundos para abrir, mas tem vezes que demora 50 segundos e da erro e tem horas que demora 20 segundos e fica muito tempo ocioso, tentei o webdriverwait mas nao deu certo, teriam alguma solução para me dar?
Esse código da o seguinte erro: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\scrapy\chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('site')
#sleep(25)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "elementEmail"))
    )
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@translate="@APP-COMMON-EMAIL"]')
email.click()
```

Comment: Esse `WebDriverWait` que você colocou está esperando no máximo 10 segundos - se você disse que o mínimo é 20, talvez está esperando pouco? Aumente para 100 segundos e veja se melhora.

Comment: Mas ai é que esta o problema, não quero que espere uma quantidade de tempo, quero que ele va automatico, fora que esse código esta dando erro

Comment: Então - o propósito do `WebDriverWait` é esperar até o elemento aparecer. Você tem que colocar um tempo bem acima do que precisa, pois ele vai esperar **no máximo esse tempo** - a idéia é que se o elemento for localizado ele **pára de esperar imediatamente**, então, você tem que dar tempo suficiente para que ele seja localizado. O código deve estar falhando porque você colocou um tempo muito pequeno, ao término de 10 segundos o elemento ainda não apareceu.

Comment: Sim, Obrigado, deu certo agora, eu havia entendido errado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode usar o WebDriverWait juntamente com o

> EC.presence_of_element_located()

ele irá esperar um tempo setado ou ate que o elemento esteja visível, porém dependendo do caso você ainda terá que colocar o sistema para esperar neste caso você usa para conseguir parar o script pelo tempo setado.

> time.sleep(time)

Aqui esta um exemplo que eu uso nos meus testes com selenium.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as time
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'tag')))
time.sleep(5)
print(element.is_displayed())
```

voce pode colocar para mostrar no terminal se o elemento está visível ou não assism você pode ver melhor o que esta acontecendo

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou, obrigado

Comment: So nao esquece de marcar que minha resposta é útil :D 
Qualquer outra duvida manda ai...

Comment: Marquei ja, valeu, até tenho, mas falaram que não é possivel alterar o nome de um pdf em python